# Install intel python fails in anaconda due to http connection error

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, intel-python

I am new to Anaconda. HTTP connection error is occurring while installing Intel Python under Anaconda.

> condaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url".

Please help me to solve this issue.

Figure shows the error message when I try to install intel python under anaconda.
[image]

Comment: Can you access any conda repositories successfully? What do you get if you do `conda search intelpython3_core`?

Answer (score 0):

It may due to proxy:

try configuring proxy according to documentation:

https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#configure-conda-for-use-behind-a-proxy-server-proxy-servers